# How to replace all non-english Alphabets(Characters) to space(s) by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Unicode XML file containing different languages. I need to replace all Non-English alphabets to space from the file. This is an example of the file. by XSLT 1.0

```
<NameValue>
    <EntityName>Kai</EntityName>
    <OriginalScriptName>住吉</OriginalScriptName>
    <OriginalScriptName>すみかい</OriginalScriptName>
    <OriginalScriptName>スシカイ</OriginalScriptName>
</NameValue>
```

expect outcome

```
<NameValue>
    <EntityName>Kai</EntityName>
    <OriginalScriptName>  </OriginalScriptName>
    <OriginalScriptName>    </OriginalScriptName>
    <OriginalScriptName>    </OriginalScriptName>
</NameValue>
```

XSLT i tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:my-scripts="urn:my-scripts" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="my-scripts"><![CDATA[
    public string fReplaceNonASCIICharacters(string inStr)
    {
         return Regex.Replace(inStr," ", @"[^\x20-\x7E]");
    }
    ]]></msxsl:script>

    <xsl:template match="OriginalScriptName">
        <xsl:value-of select="(my-scripts:fReplaceNonASCIICharacters(.))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why does your example replace 2 characters and 4 characters with 8 spaces each? More importantly, why do you need to do such replacement at all? It seems rather senseless to discard all the real information, but preserve its original size.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  thats ia a mistake, your are right only 1 to 1 replacement is required. because somettime the value will caome in like <EntityName>Kai 住 スシカイ</EntityName> I still need "Kai"...

Comment: @IanRoberts, HI Ian updated the code i tried in main post, thx

Comment: FYI, you mean non-Latin characters. There's no such thing as English characters.

Comment: @user3724711 In your example, when the input is `<EntityName>Kai 住 スシカイ</EntityName>`, you will end up with `"Kai       "` instead of `"Kai"`. That is the part that doesn't seem sensible to me.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If we're going to nitpick, then 32 -126 is printable ASCII. The Latin character set is much larger.  -- P.S. I predict than in less than 5 years you'll look back and say: I can't believe I wasted my time removing "thank you" from the Internet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes "Kai       " is good for me, because the final final out put is a  fixed length text file, so size is not the issues :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders noted with thanks :)

Comment: @user3724711 Well, then your question is really how to **keep** only printable ASCII characters and **remove** the rest - not **replace** them with spaces, isn't it? Or did you mean you want to preserve the original length of the field?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I've been doing this for a while. I don't regret editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ian's comment (and assuming we can make `spaces` long enough to cover all possible input data):

```
<xsl:variable name="ascii-letters"
  select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:param name="spaces" select="'                                                                               '"/>

<xsl:template match="OriginalScriptName">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="non-ascii-letters" select="translate(., $ascii-letters, '')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $non-ascii-letters, $spaces)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The replacement string needs as many spaces as there are characters in `translate(., $ascii-letters, '')`, otherwise you're only replacing the _first_ non-ASCII character with a space and deleting the others.

Comment: Nice solution except for the issue Ian Roberts mentioned. If the EXSLT function `str:padding` is available, you can create a suitable replacement string with `str:padding(string-length())`.

Comment: @IanRoberts, you are right of course, it seems my XPath 1.0 skills are fading, I have corrected the code for the moment by at least providing a `spaces` parameter with a couple of blanks.

Comment: Thanks all, it helps a lot:) just thinking do we have any choice to handle all the ascii chars? like " and > this kind of symbol, Actually  i am looking foe if there is a way to keep all those symbols and letters which can be key in by US keyboard ONLY i.e Ascii Oct 040 - 176 (HTML &#32; to &#126;).    I tried to key in those one by one in to the "ascii-letters xsl variable" but it failed at " position...

Comment: It is tricky if you really want to assign all the characters in the select attribute as you have to deal with quotes which are also used as string and attribute delimiters. But you can also use e.g. `<xsl:param name="ascii-letters">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"$%</xsl:param>` where you would put all characters into the contents of the `xsl:param` or `xsl:variable` and where you then don't have problems with quotes and can of course additionally use character references like `&#160;` to list characters which can't be typed that easily. Try it that way.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, It works  thanks a lot....`<xsl:param name="ascii-letters">&#32;&#33;&#34;&#35;&#36;&#37;&#38;&#39;&#40;&#41;&#42;&#43;&#44;&#45;&#46;&#47;&#48;&#49;&#50;&#51;&#52;&#53;&#54;&#55;&#56;&#57;&#58;&#59;&#60;&#61;&#62;&#63;&#64;&#65;&#66;&#67;&#68;&#69;&#70;&#71;&#72;&#73;&#74;&#75;&#76;&#77;&#78;&#79;&#80;&#81;&#82;&#83;&#84;&#85;&#86;&#87;&#88;&#89;&#90;&#91;&#92;&#93;&#94;&#95;&#96;&#97;&#98;&#99;&#100;&#101;&#102;&#103;&#104;&#105;&#106;&#107;&#108;&#109;&#110;&#111;&#112;&#113;&#114;&#115;&#116;&#117;&#118;&#119;&#120;&#121;&#122;&#123;&#124;&#125;&#126;</xsl:param>`